# Reform gem to create Devise user nested within Checklist resource -- is this possible?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, simple-form, nested-attributes, reform

I'm trying to create an event planning checklist app using Devise for the user model, the Reform gem, and simple_form.

I keep seeing this error message when I access the '/new_checklist' path: **undefined method `event_date' for #< Hash:0x007fb18f5b71a8 >**.

What am I doing wrong? For various reasons, I have my user resource nested within my checklist resource.

Here's my event checklist controller:

```
def new_checklist
  @form = EventChecklistForm.new(event_checklist: EventChecklist.new,
                            user: User.new)
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  require 'securerandom'
  has_many :checklist_items
  belongs_to :event_checklist
end
```

Checklist model:

```
class EventChecklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :checklist_items
  has_many :users
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :checklist_items
end
```

Event checklist form model:

```
class EventChecklistForm < Reform::Form
  # include DSL
  include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord

  property :event_date, on: :event_checklist
  property :code, on: :event_checklist

  property :email, on: :user
  property :password, on: :user
  property :password_confirmation, on: :user
end
```

I've also tried adding "model :event_checklist" to the end of the event checklist model, but it didn't make a difference.

And finally, the form:

```
= simple_form_for @form do |f|

  = f.input :event_date
  = f.input :code
  = f.input :email
  = f.input :password
  = f.input :password_confirmation
```

I had hoped to nest the Devise user model within the event checklist model, and create both at the same time using the Reform gem. Can this not be done? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Follow the howto on https://github.com/apotonick/reform#compositions.

Basically you have to:

```
class EventChecklistForm < Reform::Form
  include Composition
  ...
end
```

Comment: Or maybe you have to add `include Reform::Form::ActiveRecord`